# I want from a servlet to add some plain text content and two headers to the HttpServletResponse

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, httpresponse

I want to add some plain text and two headers to the `HttpServletResponse`, the code is the following:

`resp.setContentType("text/plain");`

`resp.getWriter().write(messages.get(next).getContent());`

`resp.addHeader("success", "yes");`

`resp.addHeader("hasnext", ((Boolean)hasNext).toString());`

The problem I encounter is that sending the content prevents the sending of the headers. If I don't write the content the headers are received fine, if I include the text they don't.

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try setting your headers first. Also I'm assuming you call `writer.flush()` after you are done with your response.

UPDATE

Can you check if the following works:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    response.setHeader("success", "yes");
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    writer.write("hello\n");
    writer.close();
}
```

Use `curl -i http://yourapp.appspot.com` to verify the headers.

Comment: Did you try to use `resp.getWriter().println(...)`?

Comment: Every method for output I've tried either using the PrintWriter or the ServletOutputStream has the same result.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your support !

Comment: I have found that calling resp.getWriter().flush() on the response writer causes the browser to cancel the request.  If I take out the flush(), all my code works fine.  The AppEngine docs (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/) make it clear that servlets in AppEngine are running is a sandboxed environment so that they can auto-scale effectively.  This means that some things you can do in a 'normal' or standard servlet environment do not work (for instance, keep-alive).  It seems that calling flush on the output writer is one of those things.