# How to pass tomcat server data to JQuery $.get(...,...,func) call back method

Tags: jquery, tomcat8

I'm working on a web page using JQuery on the client side and JSP and Java on the server side. I would like to use the JQuery "$.get()" method, but I don't understand how to program the server side response to the call to $.get().

On the client side, I have used the following code:

```
var fakeData = { 
    first: "Joe",
    last: "Jones"
}   

$.get("sitepage/logicalPage.func",fakeData,setLogicalPage);
```

The callback function 'setLogicalPage' is written as a client
side javascript as follows:

```
function setLogicalPage(data) {
    d_logicalPage = data.logicalPage;
}
```

On the server side, my controller, written in java, gets called and handles the case for "sitepage/logicalPage.func". It properly
records the 'fakeData'.

What I don't understand is how the server is supposed to pass the response data back to the call back function. I have searched, but I have yet not found an example on how the data should be passed back. Can some one provide a pointer to an example or explain how to pass data to the callback method?

Comment: I will leave my question open, but I just found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503308/i-want-from-a-servlet-to-add-some-plain-text-content-and-two-headers-to-the-http#6503395   and it looks like it leads me toward where I want to be. I think maybe something like: resp.setContentType("application/json"); resp.getWriter().write(myJSONdata); resp.addHeader("success", "yes"); maybe the way to go

Comment: Progress has been made. I added some console.log() statements to the callback method, setLogicalPage() and found that the callback method is being called. However, when I print the 'data' passed to the callback, I find that it is not the JSON data, but instead is the source code to my current JSP page. So, I am passing data, just not the correct data.